# Prolog Floor Puzzle

Tags: prolog

Baker, Cooper, Fletcher, Miller and Smith live in a five-story building. Baker does not live on the 5th floor and Cooper does live on the first floor. Fletcher does not live on the top or the bottom, and he is not on a floor adjacent to Smith or Cooper. Miller lives on some floor above Cooper and below the 4th floor. Who lives on what floor?

so for the following problem i tried to set it up like this

```
floor(1).
floor(2).
floor(3).
floor(4).
floor(5).

house(B,C,F,M,S) :-
   floor(B),
   floor(C),
   floor(F),
   floor(M),
   floor(S),
   B<5,C>1,F>1,F<5,M>C,M<4.
```

now as you can see i couldn't figure out how to represent the part about F and adjacent floors, also i can only guess that i need to say that each floor is not equal to each other so i dont get people living on same floor.

Comment: Cooper does live on the first floor means: `C = 1`. And you will have to insist that they are all different.

Comment: @false I think it's a typo: Cooper _does not_ live on the first floor.

Comment: And I guess there's another typo: the condition about Miller living below the 4th floor shouldn't be there (otherwise there are no solutions).

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem, all of the conditions are given by professor however she made a logical mistake if you do the problem by hand you get
5|S
4|F
3|M
2|C
1|B
as you can see if you go by rules in the end the only plase an S can live is floor 5 but that fails one of the rules so i will tel the prof that she made a mistake as far as prolog code goes i did it like this

```
floor(1).
floor(2).
floor(3).
floor(4).
floor(5).
fadjacent(X,Y):- X \= (Y + 1) ,X \= (Y - 1).
%fadjacent(X,Y):- X \= Y - 1.





house(B,C,F,M,S) :-
floor(B),
floor(C),
floor(F),
floor(M),
floor(S),
B<5,C>1,F>1,F<5,M>C,M<4,fadjacent(F,S),fadjacent(F,C),B\=C,B\=F,B\=M,B\=S,
    C\=B,C\=F,C\=M,C\=S,F\=B,F\=C,F\=M,F\=S,M\=C,M\=F,M\=B,M\=S,
    S\=C,S\=F,S\=M,S\=B.
```

which produces an answer i wanted except for that one mistake.

Comment: You should use `(=\=)/2` in place of `(\=)/2`. It happens to give the same result but in other situations it might be different.